# Bash path issue

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, spaces

I have a script which contains the following line:

```
propFile="${0%/*}/anteater.properties"
```

1. What does "${0%/*}" mean?
2. This command gives a path to the script - but there is a spaces at path and script can't find this file - how to deal with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%` operator in variable expansion removes the matching suffix pattern given to it. So `${0%/*}` takes the variable `$0`, and removes all matching `/*` at the end. This is equivalent to the command [`dirname`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dirname), which, when given a path, returns the parent directory of that path.

In order to deal with spaces in bash variable, whenever expanding the variable (i.e. whenever you write `$var`), you should quote it. In short, always use `"$var"` instead of just `$var`.

Consider reading [shell parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and [variable quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Double-Quotes.html) in the bash manual to learn more about these two subjects.

Answer (score 1):

1. strips the suffix matching `/*`, i.e. everything after last slash including the slash itself.
2. quote it wherever you use it (`cat "$propFile"`).

Comment: Quoting definitely works.  If you ever want to refer to a filename with space in it by name directly, however, you can escape your spaces with the \ character.

Comment: @asf107, and if you every want to refer to a filename stored in variable — quote it. Just in case.